# php array strtotime query

Tags: php, arrays, strtotime

I have the following code which finds the oldest date in an array, and displays 'available now' if the date is today or earlier, or 'mixed availability' if the date is in the future.

Im now trying to modify this so that if only 1 valid date (not null or 1970-01-01 which is being imported if the date is blank) is found in the array, it would display this date, or if the date is today or before today it would display 'available now'... id really appreciate any help! Many thanks in advance!

```
<?php
$avail = array($this->item->extraFields->RoomONEDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomTWODateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomTHREEDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomFOURDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomFIVEDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomSIXDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomSEVENDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomEIGHTDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomNINEDateAvailable->value, $this->item->extraFields->RoomTENDateAvailable->value);
$avail = array_filter($avail);
$avail = min($avail);
if (strtotime($avail) < time()) { ?><div class="pr-rd-avl-n">Available<br /> NOW</div>
<?php } else { ?><div class="pr-rd-avl-m">Mixed<br /> Availability</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please post your array_structure along with expected output

Comment: The array will be a range of dates with null values containing '1970-01-01' so ie 

2015-11-25, 1970-01-01, 2016-03-05, 1970-01-01, 1970-01-01, 1970-01-01, 1970-01-01, 1970-01-01, 1970-01-01, 1970-01-01

here the wanted output would be 'mixed availability' as there is more than 1 date in the future, but the output would obviously depend on the data.

I hope thats the info you wanted, thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to first filter out the `1970-01-01` date so you are working with real dates correct?

Comment: yes that would be a great start :) many thanks!

Comment: Try after the `array_filter($avail)` this: `$inval = array('1970-01-01'); $avail = array_diff($avail,$inval);`

Comment: Sorry to say that didn't work, the 1970-01-01 date is still in the array

print_r(array_values($avail));

Array ( [0] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [1] => Thursday, 03 September 2015 [2] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [3] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [4] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [5] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [6] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [7] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [8] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 [9] => Thursday, 01 January 1970 )

Comment: Hmm it seems joomla/k2 is changing the date format, but im unable to use your code $inval = array('Thursday, 01 January 1970'); $avail = array_diff($avail,$inval);